# Cartesian product of two int arrays using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, integer, java-stream

I have two arrays of int, `a = {10,20,30}` and `{1,2,3}`.

I would like to get the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of these two arrays.

When I use `List` of `Integer`s the logic works fine:

```
    List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(10,20,30);
    List<Integer> intList1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    intList.stream().flatMap(i -> intList1.stream().map(j -> new int[]{i,j})).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, when I use `int[]`, I'm getting compilation error.

> Error:(16, 79) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda
>   expression
>       no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that java.util.stream.Stream conforms to java.util.stream.IntStream

```
    int[] intArray = {10,20,30};
    int[] intArray1 = {1,2,3};
    Arrays.stream(intArray).flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(intArray1).mapToObj(j -> new int[]{j,i})).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please help me to understand what is wrong here.

P. S.

```
Arrays.stream(intArray).mapToObj(i -> new int[]{i,i+1}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Produces the out put as,  `{(10,11),(20,21),(30,31)}`.

Answer (score 10):

In the second case, `Arrays.stream(intArray)` returns an `IntStream`.
So  `flatMap()` expects as parameter a stream compatible to   :

```
Arrays.stream(intArray)
      .flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(intArray1)
                     .mapToObj(j -> new int[] { j, i }))
```

But the lambda of `flatMap()` produces a `Stream<int[]>` and you cannot map a `IntStream` to a `Stream` implicitly.
Whereas the compilation error.
So first map your `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>` :

```
List<int[]> collect = 
Arrays.stream(intArray)
      .boxed()
      .flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(intArray1)
                          .mapToObj(j -> new int[] { j, i }))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It is less efficient than your initial intention (because of the Integer boxing) but it will work.
Note that generally, you have to avoid creating a `List` of array.  These are not designed to work well together.
it is true in general and for streams too.

**Edit**

The Holger solution provided as a comment prevents the boxing :

```
List<int[]> collect = Arrays.stream(intArray)
                                  .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(intArray1)
                                                       .mapToObj(j -> new int[] { j, i }))
                                  .flatMap(Function.identity())
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It maps first the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Stream<int[]>>` and then `flatMap()` is invoked to amalgamate it into a `<Stream<int[]>`.